# kubectl top deosn't work

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, heapster

I'm using `kubernetes 1.11.0` and running heapster. When I run

```
kubectl top pod
```

It will show error

```
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get services http:heapster:)
```

while I have installed heapster already

```
kubectl create -f deploy/kube-config/influxdb/
kubectl create -f deploy/kube-config/rbac/heapster-rbac.yaml
```

Any suggest?

**Update**:

the command `kubectl top pod` works now but the endpoint doesn't work

```
kubectl get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods"
#Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request
```

Comment: What version of heapster are you using? Older versions may not work and are not recommended https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/issues/2065

Comment: @loganrakai I used the latest version, `v1.5.4`.

Comment: Could you try `kubectl -v get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods" ` tou find where you stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check and ensure that your kubectl binary is the latest? Something like

`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.0", GitCommit:"91e7b4fd31fcd3d5f436da26c980becec37ceefe", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-27T22:29:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}`

This generally happens if kubectl is older. Old kubectl versions were looking for `heapster` service to be present but new ones should not have this problem. 
Hope this helps.

In addition to above, you might want to consider moving to metrics server since heapster is on its way to being deprecated.

https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/deprecation.md

Comment: My version is `Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.0", GitCommit:"91e7b4fd31fcd3d5f436da26c980becec37ceefe", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-27T20:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.1", GitCommit:"b1b29978270dc22fecc592ac55d903350454310a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-07-17T18:43:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`
As you see that is latest version. I have so confused about this problem:/

Comment: Hey @MeysamMahmoodi have you also added metrics server to your cluster?

Comment: Yes I have installed it before heapster installation

Comment: I have pinged you on kubernetes slack also, we can probably do following to dig further: run kubectl output in debug mode to see which API call is failing.  check logs of metrics server and heapster to see where we run into problems. I think the call flow should be kubectl --> metrics server --> heapster but I'm not very sure.

Comment: Finally I solved the problem. I had two nodes that had installed different version of Kubernetes on them! 
My master node was v1.11.0 but nodes were v1.10.0. I upgraded nodes to new version and the problem is solved.
Thank you for help

Comment: Now I have new problem with `Heapster`. When I run `kubectl get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods"` It returns empty result: `{"kind":"PodMetricsList","apiVersion":"metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1","metadata":{"selfLink":"/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods"},"items":[]}` while I have 4 pods. Do I ask new question about this problem?

Comment: For this issue make  new question please.

Comment: @HarshalShah metrics server must be installed before run command kubectl top?